# CRM Multidialog Multilingual or Language Specific?

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I Created several Dialog Processes in CRM 2011, and I Exported All Translations and also Imported the Translated Version of all Entities.

From what I can see the Translations for the Texts in Dialogs are missing, and the Dialogs are available only in the Language that was used when the Dialogs were Created.

Does this means that the Dialogs are Language-Specific, or maybe I'm missing something?If Yes, what is the best aproach to make these Dialogs available in All Languages?

Thanks in Advance

Besir Kasami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a Microsoft Support KB article (april 2012), the Dialogs are language specific:

> For an organization supporting different language packs, the recommended model is to create separate equivalent dialogs for each language. The users will see the list of dialogs only for their preferred language from within the application.
>
> For organizations that require a single language dialog to be surfaced for its users, irrespective of their language settings, the recommended approach would be to customize the ribbon and add a button pointing to the URL of the dialog.

[Dialogs in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 are language specific](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2701532)